# How do I iterate over a set of folders in Windows Shell?

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, cmd

I'm currently trying to write a .cmd Windows Shell script that would iterate over a set of folders. However even the following simplest script:

```
echo "%ROOT%"
for %%f in ("%ROOT%\Binaries\" ) do (
    echo "%%f"
    if not exist "%%f\Subfolder"
        md "%%f\Subfolder"
)
```

outputs:

```
CurrentDir>echo "<ActualPathToRoot>"
"<ActualPathToRoot>"
%f\Subfolder was unexpected at this time
CurrentDir>if exists "%f\Subfolder"
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I alter that script so that it iterates over that one folder and once it see there's no subfolder named "Subfolder" it creates that subfolder? Also is there a good tutorial on writing such scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
echo %ROOT%
for /D %%f in (%ROOT%\Binaries\*) do echo %%f && if not exist %%f\Subfolder md %%f\Subfolder
```

Comment: Should it be all on a single line?

Comment: Yes.  At least in my version it worked like this.  Maybe there's a way now to do that in multiple lines, but classic batch files worked like that.  And usually people would use `goto` to have many lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was I didn't expect that linebreaks matter.

Answer (score 8):

For (sub)folder-iteration you need to use a different `for` parameter.

So if you want to **list all directories of C:** you should do this:

```
for /d %%A in (C:\*) do echo %%A
```

Note the parameter `/d` which indicates a directory. To go into subdirectories you need to do a recursive for with `/r`

```
for /r C:\Windows %%A in (*.jpg) do echo %%A
```

This would **iterate through all Windows subdirectories** looking for JPGs. Low behold you should be able to do `/d /r` and [this reference suggests](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) you can - I simply can't, but maybe you are able to do this?

A workaround I quickly jotted down is to just do a `dir` of all directories in a for loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /ad/s/b') do echo %%A
```

Note that `dir` is used in conjunction with `/ad/s/b` which performs a recursive listing of directories, printing the names of the directories found.
With these tools in your hand you should be able to do your if-subfolder construct. Note that you might need